# Component call by click Nuxt open

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, modal-dialog, vue-component

How can I make a modal window open when a button is clicked. That the modal window itself is not stored in the header?
file header:

```
<template>
    <section class="header">
      <div class="header-container">
        <div class="header_start">
          <a href="#!" class="header__logo">logo</a>
        </div>

        <div class="header-buttons_end">
          <button class="header_button" @click="isOpen = true; console.log('Button clicked')">Sign In</button>
          <teleport to="body">
            <Authorization  v-if="isOpen" />
          </teleport>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import Authorization from "@/components/ModalWindow/Authorization.vue"
</script>
```

file modal:

```
<template>
  <MazDialog v-model="isOpen" title="Dialog Title">
    <p>
      Your content
    </p>
    <template #footer="{ close }">
      <MazBtn @click="close">
        Confirm
      </MazBtn>
    </template>
  </MazDialog>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import MazDialog from 'maz-ui/components/MazDialog'

  const isOpen = ref(false)
</script>
```

I've read the documentation but I don't understand. how to call a modal window on click.
(use nuxt)

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate states and component so you have access `isOpen` everywhere. take a look at [this playground](https://You%20can%20seperate%20states%20and%20component%20so%20you%20have%20access%20everywhere.%20take%20a%20look%20at%20(this%20playground)%5Bhttps://play.vuejs.org/#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%5D)

state.ts file:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'

export const isOpen = ref(false)
```

Modal file:

```js
<script setup>
import { isOpen } from './state';
</script>

<template>
    <dialog :open="isOpen">
        <p> Your content </p>
    </dialog>
</template>
```

other files:

```js
<script setup>
import ModalVue from './Modal.vue'
import { isOpen } from './state';
</script>

<template>
  <ModalVue></ModalVue>

  <button @click="isOpen = !isOpen">
    {{ isOpen ? 'close' : 'open' }} dialog
  </button>
</template>
```